# What is the best way to handle Chinese names in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Salesforce separates family and personal names according to western convention.

That is the first name is personal and the last is a family name. This can be changed by changing the salesforce locale (say from the US to China) so that a the first name is the familyname and the last name(s) are personal

So in the vanilla SF John Smith appears as John Smith. If you switch to the Chinese localisation it would appear as Smith John.

Equally in vanilla Lim Keat Song would appear as Keat Song Lim, but would be correct in the chinese localisation as Lim Keat Song.

My problem is that about 30% of my contacts have East Asian names and so neither localisation is entirely satisfactory.

What are the the best ways of resolving this on a standard contact object?

I've asked the question on [salesforce](http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000ezcvEAA) and as far as I can see there isn't much on this on google.

I'm asking this because whilst I can solve it - probably along the lines of the SD question - it's probably a known problem and I would like to find the best solution rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your idea.

We add two custom fields as Formula on the Contact object.
One custom field called Last Name refer to the Standard Last Name field on the Contact,
the other called First Name refer to the Standard First Name field on the Contact.

Therefore, you don't need to do any data import to these custom fields, but only define how to display your customized Last Name and First Name fields in the Contact display.

And this layout of Last Name and First Name will not change with users' localisation setting.

This may be not a perfect way to solve this, I wish it would help.

Comment: I like that. So if you have say a "Chinese" check box. Then chinese_name__c formula field = IF(chinese_checkbox__c=TRUE,last_name__c & first_name__c,first_name__c & last_name__c). Then for addressing letters you do something like IF(chinese_checkbox__c=TRUE,chinese_name,name)